# Silverlight Telerik GridView MaxLength?

Tags: silverlight, gridview, telerik, maxlength

Im using a telerik gridview for silverlight and Im trying to programatically set the maximum character length on each individual column after the gridview is populated with data.
I want to make it so when the user is inserting or editing a column's cell, the maximum (char) length is set based on a control records max length. So far Ive only been able to set the MaxWidth, but that doesnt help me because the column header is always longer than the atual text allowed, and the MaxWidth sets the column width in pixels, not the columns editing max character length. Can someone point me in the right direction. I can provide some code if need be.

Ive tried setting it to
column.CellEditTemplate.SetValue(TextBoxEditor.MaxLengthProperty, MYMAXLENGTH);

but it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
Style textBoxStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
textBoxStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.MaxLengthProperty, myMaxLength));
(this.MyGrid.Columns[0] as GridViewBoundColumnBase).EditorStyle = textBoxStyle;
```

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/best-way-to-set-maxlength-on-gridviewdatacolumn.aspx

Comment: This worked. I read that thread probably 10 times, but as Im new to silvelright, wpf and telerik, I didnt understand what they meant by EditorStyle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your grid's data context is or where the "control record" is, but perhaps something like this would help?

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding MyData, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox MaxLength="{Binding MyMaxLength, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Or, if you're not using a view-model and need to bind to a property of the UserControl, then use ElementName instead of Source on the TextBox binding. (Although you can't really use ElementName unless you also incorporate something like this: [ElementName binding inside of a cell template](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/elementname-binding-inside-of-celltemplate.aspx#1187483).)

Comment: No by the control record, its my own custom object. It holds things like the record length, description, fieldname1, fieldname2, etc. Im binding my GridViews itemssource by pointing an it to something from the DB. I need to programatically set each individual columns maxLength, so a template wouldn't work. Basically the control record is holding the columns maxLength in the database and then i want to set that column on the gridview to its maxLength.